# Cloning AdSense ads using jQuery

Tags: jquery, adsense, ads

Am I allowed to clone an AdSense ad using jQuery (and delete the old one I just cloned), say for instance if I need to transfer it from one layout to another?

Answer (score 1):

Unsure about the legalities but why clone?  Can't you grab the css that the ad is using and simply re-create those in your own css that changes the look, placement etc?

**edit**

This is interesting;

http://google.about.com/od/adsense/tp/adsensedonts.htm
 Especially item 3

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. One is (currently) not allowed to edit AdSense's CSS. What I want to know though, is whether one is allowed to manipulate the DOM by duplicating ads and hiding/showing them according to say, if the user is in newspaper mode, blog mode etc.

Comment: Again, not knowing the full legalities involved, my personal opinion is that you'd be allowed to (duplicate) them but not hide them.  This is a question you might be best asking Google.

Comment: I can't contact them because I just launched my site and I don't yet qualify for private consultation, nor can I put my livelihood on stake just because of your personal opinion. I do, however, sincerely appreciate your response.

Comment: Yeah my "opinion" should in no way influence your livelihood. :)  It's an interesting problem none the less and I'm going to follow this thread.

Comment: Very nice. For what it's worth, this one is also interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229411/google-adsense-inside-a-jquery-dialog